# c++: how to delete a pointer created/modified in an async function?

Tags: c++, pointers, asynchronous, memory

I am very confused of how to delete a pointer that's has been called from async function.
What do I have:

```
Obj* doStuff(int size){
  Obj *myObject = new Obj(size);//where do I delete this?
  myObject.doSomeOtherStuffWhichChangesMyObject();
  return myObject;
}

int main (){
       for (int i = 0; i < CORES; i++)
        {
                std::shared_future<Obj*> f = std::async(std::launch::async, doStuff,5);
                futures.push_back(f);
        }
return;
}
```

I am not very sure of the proper design to do it.
My first thought was to create the new Obj* before calling the function:

```
  Obj* doStuff(Obj *myObject){

      myObject.doSomeOtherStuffWhichChangesMyObject();
      return myObject;
  }

int main (){
       for (int i = 0; i < CORES; i++)
        {
                Obj *myObject = new Obj(5);//where do I delete this?
                std::shared_future<Obj*> f = std::async(std::launch::async, doStuff, myObject);
                futures.push_back(f);
        }
return;
}
```

Then I realized that I cannot delete the new Obj because it's been used by other async processes. So my last solution is to create a double pointer** **before** the *for* loop to store the address of every new Obj created in the for loop and delete everything **after the loop**. However, I am not sure if this is the proper design to do it. Can you please suggest a way that would solve this problem? I think I mostly need a design/examples of how to delete a pointer created (i) inside a function (ii) inside a for loop.
Thanks

Comment: If you really need pointers (these days mostly for polymorphism) then use *smart* pointers. If there's no polymorphism involved I would recommend you to use plain objects.

Comment: I am not working with polymorphism, I am working on graphics project and the Obj contains a huge amount of data, so in my async process I have to collect a vector with pointers of these objects and do some other processes with them. So I was wondering if I want to delete the Obj *myObject = new Obj(5); manually, how would I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Take and return `std::shared_ptr<Obj>` to signal that ownership of the pointer is shared. This will also automatically take care of freeing the Obj when the everybody is done with it (all shared_ptr go out of scope).

Look at std::make_shared for a simple way to create the shared pointer.

Comment: what is the way to do it using old school c++? I am trying to figure out the proper design without using smart pointers

Comment: The old way is to implelemt your own smart pointer. Which is rather pointless.

Comment: ok, you are right, so let's go back to the smart pointers :) what should  the return object of the async function be?  std::shared_future< std::shared_ptr<Obj> > sharedFuture?

Comment: I am sorry If I am not clear with the workflow, in sort what I want to do is: 1) create  std::vector<std::shared_future<std::shared_ptr<Obj>>> futures 2) start async by creating  std::shared_future< std::shared_ptr<Obj> > sharedFuture 3) push back sharedFuture to futures 3) after finishing the loop  I want to store the futures in another/bigger object 4) finally delete the pointers